# Add CSS class to mail_to ruby on rails helper

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I know that you can add HTML classes to link_to helpers like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Logout', logout_path, class: 'primary-link-style' %>
```

But what about the mail_to helper? There doesn't seem to be a way to add a HTML/CSS class like you can with the link_to helper.

[The docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/mail_to) only talk about examples of inline styling which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method signature from the docs you linked to:

> ```
> mail_to(email_address, name = nil, html_options = {}, &block)
> ```

That third argument, `html_options`, works just like the same argument of `link_to`:

```
<%= mail_to "foo@example.com", "Email me", class: "primary-link-style" %>
```